How to deploy hadoop Yarn on kubernetes
How can I deploy Hadoop on a Kubernetes cluster, particularly with a focus on using Minikube, Docker desktop,on Windows
I installed minikube,docker desktop and kubectl.
I configured the environment variable for kubectl
then I start minikube with minikube start
But then I don't know what to do and im not sure if I am even in the right direction
